# Wix Patch- On uninstallation of patch Restart of system dialog is popped up

Tags: wix, installation, patch

I have been generating the patch file by comparing the older version and newer version pdb files.
The patch file (msp) is installed successfully and the Restart of system dialog is **not popped up**.
On uninstallation of patch **restart of system dialog is popped up**.
Please let me know how I can restrict restart of system dialog on uninstallation.

Patch file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Patch 
      AllowRemoval="yes"
      Manufacturer="Test"
      MoreInfoURL="http://www.test.com/"
      DisplayName="Patch 1.0.1"
      Description="Patch"
      Classification="Update" 
        >

    <Media Id="5000" Cabinet="RTM.cab">
      <PatchBaseline Id="RTM">
        <Validate ProductId="no" />        
      </PatchBaseline>
    </Media>

    <PatchFamilyRef Id="PatchFamily"/>
  </Patch>

  <Fragment>
    <PatchFamily Id='PatchFamily' Version='1.0.1' Supersede='yes' >
      <!--<ComponentRef Id="C__F12B37CBEAE157D538B2BAC1CF30713C"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="C__3430F83A3728AE39FA075656EBFCA0BD"/>-->
    </PatchFamily>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a property that does this, but I am not sure if it works with a Patch or not.

`<Property Id="MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL" Value="Disable" />`

That should get done what you are trying to do. Let me know if you have other questions about it.